# Are the following expressions the same: "в Мой рук" and "в руки мне"?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

I heard the expression "**в руки мне**" (=into my hands, *genitive plural*) in a song. As far as  I know, to say "*into*" we have to use accusative case. But in that expression it is in genitive case. Can we rewrite that expression like:"**в Мой рук**" (*accusative plural*) ?

Comment: You can write **"в мои руки"** (proper spelling of accusative, plural), Keep in mind, it should agree with the rest of your phrase.

Comment: You should give us more context at where you wish to use this phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us see where your confusion starts.One hand is рука, the genitive from it is чего?руки, the accusative is во что? в руку.And all these are singular.

Now two hands is **руки**(nominative ),нет чего? **рук** (genitive plural),во что? **в руки** (accusative plural).

Рука is feminine, so it **can't be** *мой--accusative singular +рук (genitive plural ).В руки is correct.

Answer (score 2):

A small clarification to the answers.
These words are spelled the same but pronounced differently:

ру́ки - nominative or accusative plural, accent on the first syllable. "в мои ру́ки"

руки́ - genitive singular, accent on the second syllable. "взмах руки́"

Answer (score 1):

> "в руки мне"

Here руки is in Accusative plural, not Genitive. The word order is non-default, the default would be мне в руки.

The singular form would be

> в мою руку or мне в руку

At the same time,

> "в Мой рук"

is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this song? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGSBJXxmbNg

Songwriters and poets usually have a freedom to bend regular grammar rules, so their texts sound better. Thatswhy songs and poems can hardly be translated literally. I would definitely not learn russian grammar from song lyrics, esp. from old folk music.

As V.V. said, "в мой рук" is definitely wrong. Read his answer for the correct explanation of grammatical cases.

Answer (score 0):

> I heard the expression "в руки мне" (=into my hands, genitive plural) in a song

It means "*Give me in [my] hands*". "Мне" is Dative and "в руки" is Accusative plural.

> Can we rewrite that expression like:"в Мой рук" (accusative plural) ?

It seems you just confused which form is which. "Рук" is Genitive plural, not Accusative.